# Help to make a section plane view of house interior

Tags: rendering

[image]I have worked up a crude model of a small house and want to make a section view to show the interior.  It is build up of many blocks, a roof material, a cladding material and other materials for doors windows and furniture.  I have tried the Section View Plane addon, but cannot get materials to display consistantly.  I cannot understand how to work with the BlenderBIM Add-on, and shaders are completely beyond me.  Please can someone explain how this can be achieved relatively simply.

Thank you
As suggested I have attached and image achieved by hiding roof elements, using the camera clipping, and editing with gimp, but I would still like to use a section plane if possible.  Thank you for your beautiful and detailed explanation of the shader technique. I will give it a go, but I fear it is beyond me.

Comment: What do you mean "cannot get the materials do display"? To get a material to display, you first have to create and assign a material, and then switch to rendered view mode.

Comment: You need to provide an image of your model which you can insert into your question so that we can see what you're talking about. In any case both of the addons you mention are 3rd-party addons, not part of Blender, so you should ask their developers about them.

Answer (score 2):

You can make nodes like this:

[image]

This will make surfaces transparent on the one side of the Empty:

[image]

You can move and rotate the Empty to adjust the cut.

Then it goes to multiple materials group these nodes by selecting them and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>:

[image]

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter and leave nodegroup

And you can reuse it in other materials <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> ⇾ Group ⇾ NodeGroup name

[image]

Put it in every material right before Surface output.

For EEVEE Alpha clip should be enabled:

[image]

[image]

You can also make inner parts of the mesh looks solid, if you color back of faces using emission node

[image]

Works with EEVEE and Cycles

[image]